# Why does the direction of the plane's velocity matter in the Hafele and Keating Experiment to verify gravitational time dilation?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

I found this confusing because a plane's velocity is defined relative to the ground. So, no matter what the plane's direction is, the relative speed of the clocks (hence the Lorentz factor) on the plane is the same compared with the clocks on the ground. But why the time dilation is different when the plane was flying eastwards and westwards?

Answer (score 3):

You are quite correct that a plane's velocity is defined relative to the ground, and the direction of the flight matters because the ground is moving. The circumference of the Earth is about 40000 kilometres and the Earth rotates once every 24 hours, so a "stationary" point on the equator is actually moving eastwards at 40000 km per 24 hours or about 460 m/s (a bit over a thousand miles per hour).

So when you fly east at $x$ m/s your total speed is $460+x$, while when you fly west your total speed is $460-x$. The different speeds cause different time dilations.

There is a subtlety here because you might argue that if speed is always relative it should be only the speed relative to the ground that matters. This isn't the case because the ground is not an inertial frame. Obviously not since it is moving in a circle as the Earth rotates. We define the time in a frame that is not rotating, and it is the speed in this frame that determines the time dilation.

Comment: Exactly *how* is it determined that the Earth itself is rotating, and rotating in relation to what? I realise it's possible to say "the Hafele-Keating experiment shows the Earth is not inertial must be rotating", but that does not explain why in theory there should be an asymmetry (when the OP is clearly thinking everything is on an equal footing in relativity), nor is it being specific about exactly what physical entity or entities form the anchor for the non-rotating frame in practice, and why this non-rotating frame seems to be privileged.

Comment: @Steve in relativity (special and general) we can measure a property of an observer called their [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration). This is not a relative quantity like velocity. It is an absolute quantity and all observers in all frames, moving, rotating or whatever, will agree on the value of the proper acceleration. An inertial observer has a zero proper acceleration while an observer not in an inertial frame has a non-zero proper acceleration. So it is always possible to tell what frames are inertial and what frames are non-inertial.

Comment: The observer in a rotating frame has a non-zero proper acceleration, basically due to the centripetal force required for rotation. It is the zero proper acceleration of the non-rotating frame that makes the non-rotting frame privileged.

Comment: This is not a million miles from the twin paradox. In this we point out that one of the twins accelerates away then back, and this makes that twin different from the one who stayed motionless. The accelerating twin has a non-zero proper acceleration while the motionless twin has a zero proper acceleration and this is what makes the difference just like in our case above of the rotating frame.

Comment: In my view this merely rehearses the distinction between inertial and non-inertial frames, and affirms our ability to distinguish experimentally which one the Earth occupies. It does not identify why in theory it is that the Earth should occupy a non-inertial frame, nor exactly which heavenly bodies occupy the inertial frame against which the Earth's rotation is ultimately measured (and why those bodies have the privilege of being inertial).

Comment: In other words, what physical attributes or relations exist, to explain why the distinction manifests as the Earth undergoing rotation whilst the things in the inertial frame remain still, rather than the symmetrical case of the Earth occupying the inertial frame (and thus remaining still) and the other things undergoing rotation around it?